# Which order should I read the Humble Bundle IDW Star Trek comics in?

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order, star-trek-eu, idw-comics

I recently purchased the [Humble Star Trek Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/books) (presented by IDW). They've included 18 volumes of comic books (84 comic issues in total). I'm fairly sure that the stories are 'more or less' self contained, and unlike the Transformers series a month ago, Star Trek novels and comics have always been 'vignettes' or glimpses into the untold stories between the various series and films.

Still, I do find myself wondering how best to 'avoid jumping back and forth in time' as I read them, (aside from the obvious TOS/TNG/DS9 demarcations) to try and follow any story continuities that may exist.

Is anyone familiar with these titles enough to take a guess at a 'best reading order'?

My best guess is:

***TOS Stuff***

- Star Trek: Gold Key Archives, Vol. 1
- Star Trek: Assignment Earth - follow up to "TOS: Assignment Earth"
- Star Trek: Mirror Images - prequel to "TOS: Mirror Mirror"
- Star Trek: Burden of Knowledge - new tale of TOS crew
- Star Trek: Romulans Treasury Edition - uniforms suggest TOS era
- Star Trek: Year Four - The Enterprise Experiment - Cover art suggests TAS (Animated Series) era
- Star Trek: Mission's End - the "final" mission of TOS era
- Star Trek: Best of Klingons - Uniforms suggest TOS Movie era.

  ---

***TNG Stuff***

- Star Trek Classics, Vol. 1 - TNG, uniforms suggest Post-Generations era.
- Star Trek Classics, Vol. 2 - "Volume 2" though uniforms suggest TNG, DS9 and post Generations eras.
- Star Trek: The Next Generation - Hive - TNG, uniforms suggest Post-Generations era with flashbacks.

  ---

***DS9 Stuff***

- Star Trek: Deep Space Nine - Fool's Gold - Obviously a DS9 story.

  ---

***JJ Trek Stuff***

- Star Trek: Countdown - official TNG Movie Era -> JJ Trek backstory.
- Star Trek: Spock Reflections - Touted as "a followup to Countdown"
- Star Trek: Movie Adaptation - JJ Trek Film
- Star Trek: Nero - touted as Nero's version of the events in the JJ Trek film.
- Star Trek: Countdown to Darkness - prequel to "Into Darkness"
- Star Trek Vol. 1 - Continuing adventures of JJ Trek crew, in TOS-inspired stories.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read all of those, and given that it's been almost a full year since the question was asked, I'm sure you HAVE by now (maybe you could post an answer!) but here's a thing to consider:

Things like the 'Classics' collections will not interconnect (much) - they are examples of the best stories from a comics run (or a specific part of a comic's run) and may not follow a particular story arc.

Other than that note (which is primarily for TNG) I'd recommend you stick with the ordering you chose.  TNG/DS9 don't have much to organize, and your organization looks good to me for TOS and Abramsverse.

I might suggest switching *Countdown to Darkness* and Vol 1, though - I'd be willing to guess Vol 1 doesn't deal with anything post-*Into Darkness*, and the *Countdown to Darkness* probably leads right up to the start of the movie (like the original Countdown did).